# LLDB customize print of template class

Tags: python, c++, debugging, lldb

I use LLDB as my debugger, and want it to print my template class `MyArray<N>` in a customized format.

I read the LLDB document, and come up with python script that can get public and private data members of `MyArray<N>`. However, I don't know how to get `N` (the template parameter), neither do I know how to get result return by `MyArray<N>::size()`.

Here is the code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
class MyArray
{
public:
    MyArray(){data = new int[N];}
    ~MyArray(){if (data) delete[] data;}

    int size() const{ return N;}
    int& operator[](size_t i) { return data[i];}
    int const& operator[](size_t i) const { return data[i];}

private:
    int* data = nullptr;
};

template<int N>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const MyArray<N>& arr)
{
    os << "N = " << arr.size() << std::endl;
    os << "elements in array:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0) os << ", ";
        os << arr[i];
    }
    return os << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyArray<10> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        arr[i] = 10 + i;
    std::cout << arr << std::endl;  // Yeah, I can use this for print. but I want this during LLDB debug

    return 0;
}
```

//// Update: Add corresponding lldb config
`~/.lldbinit`:

```
command script import ~/.lldbcfg/print_my_array.py
```

`~/.lldbcfg/print_my_array.py`:

```py
def print_my_array(valobj, internal_dict):
    #N = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName("size") # failed
    N = 10
    data = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName("data")
    info = ''
    for i in range(N):
        if(i>0): info += ', '
        info += str(data.GetChildAtIndex(i).GetValueAsSigned(0))
    info += ')'
    return info

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -P MyArray<10> -F ' + __name__ + '.print_my_array')
```

Comment: lldb should be able to get the template argument value (along with the kind & type, which it currently does fetch) at least for scalar typed template arguments.  That requires a little design, but shouldn't be all that hard.  I didn't see an ER for this on the llvm bug site (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues).  Feel free to file a request for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to store the value of `N` as static member:

```
template<int N>
class MyArray
{
public:
    static constexpr const int n = N;
};
```

Supposed `MyArray` is not your type you can infer the template argument via a trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct get_value;

template <int N>
struct get_value<MyArray<N>> {
     static constexpr const n = N;
};
```

Comment: This method looks cool to me! But I guess calling `get_value<MyArray<N>>` is required. Should I call it in `print_my_array.py` config file?